# Как создать реализацию абстрактного действия ABSTRACT CASE с несколькими параметрами?

Tags: lsfusion

В lsFusion 3.0 легко создается абстрактное действие и добавляются его реализации с одним параметром. Например так:

```
CLASS TrafficLight {
    red 'Red',
    yellow 'Yellow',
    green 'Green'
}

crossroads ABSTRACT CASE (TrafficLight);

crossroads(TrafficLight t) + WHEN t = TrafficLight.red THEN {MESSAGE 'Stop - ' + staticCaption(t);}
```

Но, стоит добавить еще один параметр и сервер перестает запускаться. Пример ниже уже не работает

```
CLASS TrafficLight {
    red 'Red',
    yellow 'Yellow',
    green 'Green'
}

CLASS Vehicle {
    truck 'Truck',
    car 'Car'
}

crossroads ABSTRACT CASE (TrafficLight, Vehicle);

crossroads(TrafficLight t, Vehicle v) + WHEN t = TrafficLight.red THEN {MESSAGE 'Stop ' + staticCaption(v);}
```

Пока, в качестве workaround, использую ABSTRACT LIST и IF...THEN в добавляемых реализациях, но как сделать это без костылей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если коротко, нужно в WHEN добавить v IS Vehicle:

```
crossroads(TrafficLight t, Vehicle v) + WHEN t = TrafficLight.red AND v IS Vehicle THEN {MESSAGE 'Stop ' + staticCaption(v);}
```

Более длинное объяснение состоит в следующем. Дело в том, что lsFusion по большому счету 
не является строго типизированным языком. То есть задание классов параметров это всего лишь помощь в поиске свойств, чтобы каждый раз не указывать их сигнатуру, в логике вычислений эти классы никак не участвуют. Соответственно в вашем случае, добавление реализации эквивалентно:

```
crossroads(t, v) + WHEN t = TrafficLight.red THEN {MESSAGE 'Stop ' + staticCaption(v);}
```

Соответственно платформа не может (да и не должна) вывести класс у реализации и соответственно дает ошибку:

```
Features:45:1 wrong signature of implementation p6441 'Vehicle(пр.)' {I/0 -> I/1} (at crossroads [Features(28:46)]) for abstract property p6437
    specified: I/0 -> up{[Features.TrafficLight 'TrafficLight' [Features(15:1)]]}
    expected : I/0 - up{[Features.TrafficLight 'TrafficLight' [Features(15:1)]]},I/1 - up{[Features.Vehicle 'Vehicle' [Features(21:1)]]})
```

Аналогичная проблема может возникнуть скажем, если вы сделаете:

```
f(A a) = 1;
run() {
    FOR f(A a) DO // выдаст ошибку что операция не корректна
       MESSAGE a;
}
```

Другое дело, что да это не всегда очевидно и в будущих версиях платформы явная типизация будет скорее всего автоматически добавлять IF a IS A, то есть верхний пример будет эквивалентен:

```
f(A a) = 1 IF a IS A; // последнее условие добавится автоматически
```

Более того первый шаг в этом направлении уже сделан. Такое неявное добавление условия на класс уже происходит при использовании ABSTRACT без WHEN, то есть:

```
f(A a) += 1; // автоматически добавится IF a IS A
```